# Schedule scripts to run every so often

Tags: sails.js

I was following the platzi tutorial on writing a script - https://courses.platzi.com/classes/sails-js/concepto/growth-and-monetization6001/notifications/material/ - Notifications.

He writes the script but doesn't show us how to schedule it to run. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Your link is to a site that requires you to pay to view. You could be better served by adding an example to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it to run as a scheduled job on your cloud platform like Heroku. 
If you use Heroku you can install the `Heroku Scheduler` as an add on. Then you configure it to run your script.

```
sails run send-email-reminders
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: What about on localhost? Is this possible?

Comment: i was using digitalocean - because on heroku its 7$ per month and i cant get a domain. Do you know how to do this on digital ocean?